# How can I control a Windows GUI application from Perl?

Tags: perl, winapi

I have a Win32 GUI proccess. Is there any way to control the GUI proccess input within another process (application built in Perl)? the user have a scanning system i want to identify when the keys dispatched by the scanning system check them if they are digits and then suffix them with \n character then send them to the GUI application?

Answer (score 4):

See [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::GuiTest) which allows you to send key presses and mouse clicks to any Windows application.

It also comes with a [recorder](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KARASIK/Win32-GuiTest-1.56/Recorder/) to record user actions for later replay.

Comment: The recorder not exactly help here.

Comment: @Thor You edited your post after I posted my answer to reflect the true requirements. "*not exactly help*"? What kind of attitude is that?

Comment: Thanks anyway for your try to help ,maybe i didn't explain my requiremnet as it should be (my problem )

Answer (score 2):

Paul Fenwick wrote an article for [The Perl Review](http://www.theperlreview.com) about playing Mineweeper from Perl using his [SweeperBot](http://sweeperbot.org/) program. He uses [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GuiTest) to make the magic.